# Django query join with another query on the same table

Tags: mysql, django, join

I have a model like this:

```
class mymodel(models.Model):
    user1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    user2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    paid = models.FloatField(default=0)
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=REASON_NAMES, null=True, blank=True)
```

and I have two queries like this:

```
users_trx1 = mymodel.objects.values('user1').annotate(r1_c=Count(
            Case(
                When(reason='REASON1', then=1),
                output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        )).annotate(r2_c=Count(
            Case(
                When(reason='REASON2', then=1),
                output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        )).order_by('user1')
```

The second query gets the sum paid to user2:

```
users_trx2 = mymodel.objects.values('user2').annotate(r1_s=Sum(
            Case(
                When(reason='REASON1', then='paid'),
                default=0.0,
                output_field=FloatField()
            )
        )).annotate(r2_s=Sum(
            Case(
                When(reason='REASON2', then='paid'),
                default=0.0,
                output_field=FloatField()
            )
        )).order_by('user2')
```

Now I need a way to left join the two queries. Meaning, that I need a new query that will get me in each row: (user1, r1_c, r1_s, r2_c, r2_s).
I need the join to get `user2` values from `users_trx2` query that match `user1` from `users_trx1` query.

I'm using Django 1.11 with mysql backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search I think that Django ORM does not support such complex queries so I used raw SQL at last to get my results.